# Is there a way to prevent that a WPF page was navigated away?

Tags: wpf, navigation

I'm building a WPF navigation app, with pages.
I want to ask the user if he want to save the changes when he leaves a page.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register for the `NavigationService.Navigating` event.  Don't forget to remove your registration when you are done, since `NavigationService` sticks around basically forever.

When you get the Navigating event and there are changes, show a MessageBox to confirm with the user or give them a chance to save their data.  If they hit Cancel, set `e.Cancel = true` to cancel the navigation.