# Open a hyperlink URI (www.google.com) in a web browser( IE or chrome) through code in C# WPF forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im working on a project which has hyperlinks in it. I used DataGridHyperlinkColumn to populate the URI's in a single column. 
Whenever I click on a URI, it gets opened in both browser and the wpf window. I could prevent the URI opening in web browser by using hyperlink.RequestNavigate().

but I need the URI to be opened only in web browser and not in the WPF window. I have attached my XAML and C# code below.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgUsers"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" BorderThickness="0" CanUserResizeRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HeadersVisibility="None" Focusable="False" Visibility="{Binding DgVisibility}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding WebSite}"  Width="*" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True"  >
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <!--EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DG_Hyperlink_Click"/-->
                    </Style>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# Code Follows below.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();

    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { WebSite = new Uri("http://www.google.com") });
    users.Add(new User() { WebSite = new Uri("http://www.yahoo.com") });
    users.Add(new User() { WebSite = new Uri("http://www.gmail.com") });
    //DgVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    //userslink = users;
    dgUsers.ItemsSource = users;

 }

 public class User
 {
     public Uri WebSite { get; set; }
 }

 private void DG_Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
     Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(link.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri));
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tested your code, it seems that all is working well(an hyperlink was opened only at the windows browser), so I think you have some additional style for your  DataGridHyperlinkColumn, this style is making the problem(for example; opens your hyperlink in additional window). So try to define the next e.Handled = true; in your event handler.

Comment: Try opening a link with 'cmd /c start http://zzz.com' instead of simple url.

Comment: @Ilan even after adding e.Handled = true, the same problem repeats. the chrome browser takes 2sec approximately to open the link. and the same link is opened in my WPF form/window. I need it only on browser and not in WPF window.

Comment: @Alex I tried to open through CMD. the result is same. the link is opened in both chrome browser and WPF window

Comment: Another idea - use text column with custom template containing text only, with interaction trigger to bind mouse click to a handler.

Comment: A collegue suggested one more idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683353/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-that-a-wpf-page-was-navigated-away

Comment: @Alex if we change the hyperlink to textblock. then the link wont appear like a hyperlink right? it will appear like a simple text. like no blue color and no underline.

Comment: Add a style with Foreground set to red/blue on MouseOver trigger to mimic url look and feel. This is basically what Hyperlink control does.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me. :D changed the hyperlink to textblock and the url opens only in browser and not in same window. thank you once again, @AlexSeleznyov

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov when i select the the link. the complete block turns to blue. how to disable the selected item after clicking it?

Comment: Not sure I can understand what you're after here. What do you mean by 'complete block'? Paste some code here so we can be on the same page.

Comment: I have solved it. but now I have a new issue.

I used a ListBox to populate urls. when i move my mouse over it. I could see a Hover Effect on ListItem. I need to remove that Effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from comments:

Use text column with custom template containing text only, with interaction trigger to bind mouse click to a handler.

Add a style with Foreground set to red/blue on MouseOver trigger to mimic url look and feel. This is basically what Hyperlink control does.